# Tensorflow: how to stop small values leaking through pruning?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

The documentation for [PolynomialDecay](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/api_docs/python/tfmot/sparsity/keras/PolynomialDecay) suggests that by default, `frequency=100` so that pruning is only applied every 100 steps. This presumably means that the parameters which are pruned to 0 will drift away from 0 during the other 99/100 steps. So at the end of the pruning process, unless you are careful to have an exact multiple of 100 steps, you well end up with a model that is not perfectly pruned but which has a large number of near-zero values.

How does one stop this happening? Do you have to tweak frequency to be a divisor of the number of steps? I can't find any code samples that do that...

Answer (score 0):

As per [this example in the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/pruning_with_keras#train_and_evaluate_the_model_against_baseline): while training the `tfmot.sparsity.keras.UpdatePruningStep()` callback must be registered:

```
callbacks = [
  tfmot.sparsity.keras.UpdatePruningStep(),
  …
]

model_for_pruning.fit(…, callbacks=callbacks)
```

This will ensure that the mask is applied (and so weights set to zero) when the training ends.
https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/blob/master/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/sparsity/keras/pruning_callbacks.py#L64